# How to download a file from the web using Android 1.6

Tags: android

I am trying to download a zipped file from the web on the first instance of the application; can someone point me to a tutorial for this (I don't see good documentation on developer.android)?  I understand how to check if it's the initial start or not, and also how to use java.util.zip once I get the file, but it's the in-between where I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is about how to download the file.  So, to download a file, use code similar to the following:

```
 URL u = new URL("http://www.example.com/downloadfile.zip");
    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.setDoOutput(true);
    c.connect();

    FileOutputStream fNew = new FileOutputStream(new File(root,"downloadfile.zip"));

    InputStream inStream = c.getInputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int inlen = 0;
    while ( (inlen = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
         fNew.write(buffer,0, inlen);
    }
    fNew.close();
    inStream.close();
```

Of course, wrap with appropriate error checking